# Escape single and double quotes in DataFlow parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to use the below value as a default parameter value in DataFlow
Evaluate "Manage",CALCULATE(ManageROWS('Date'))

This contains both single and double quotes, so this is the below error i am getting when enclosing the above value in single quotes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I got same error in my environment:**

[image]

Using below extraction `'Evaluate "Manage",CALCULATE(ManageROWS(\'Date\'))'` working fine.

[image]